# Return all parameters even if no records found

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

How would I return a parameter that had no data in the server?

Sending multiple parameters over to a PHP script in an attempt to return data for each parameter here:

```
 var cntnum = $('#cntnum').val().trim().toUpperCase().split("\n");

 $.post('containerCheck.php', {cntnum:cntnum}, function(data)
 {
   var obj = JSON.parse(data);
   $('#content').empty();
   var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function(item)
   {
     return '<tr><td>'+item.CONTAINER_NUMBER+'</td><td>'+item.LOCATION+'</td></tr>';
   });
   $('#content').html(htmlToInsert);
 });
```

The cntnum will look like this: "NUM111","NUM222","NUM333"

On the server, containerCheck.php looks something like this:

```
 <?PHP
   $containers = $_POST['cntnum']; 

   $containersArray = preg_replace('/\n$/','',preg_replace('/^\n/','',preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/',"\n",$containers)));

   $select = "SELECT CONTAINER_NUMBER, LOCATION FROM INVENTORY WHERE CONTAINER_NUMBER IN ('".implode("','",$containersArray)."')";
   $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $select) or die(mysqli_error());

   $out = array(); 
   while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
   {
     $out[] = $row;
   }
   echo json_encode($out);
   mysqli_free_result($query);  
 ?>
```

The query runs with all 3 (or more) parameters that were passed from the JavaScript.

Here is the problem:  If one of the parameters returns no data, the PHP will return only the values that had data behind it.

So containers NUM111 and NUM222 may have data, but NUM333 may not.  The code I used above will only display 2 records even though 3 was sent over to the server.

I need to be able to display all of the containers regardless if there was no data behind it.

### Edit

If the user entered NUM111, NUM222, NUM333 and only the first 2 had any data in the table, I want to be able to display which ones had data:

```
 *************************
 * CONTAINER *  LOCATION * 
 *************************
 *  NUM111   * NEW YORK  *
 *************************
 *  NUM222   * DELEWARE  *
 *************************
 *  NUM333   * NOT FOUND *
 *************************
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it into two parts:

1. Preparing the data returned from the server
2. Rendering

   You'll get something like:

   ```
   var results = [];
     obj.forEach(function(item) {
        results[item.CONTAINER_NUMBER] = item.LOCATION
     });

     var html = cntnum.map(function(container) {
       var num = item.CONTAINER_NUMBER
       return '<tr><td>'+num+'</td><td>'+results[num]+'</td></tr>'
     });
   ```